# Error while loading ggplot2 package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get the following error when I try to load `ggplot2`. I tried to uninstall `scales` and reinstall it but for some reason R can't find the package when I want to remove the package...

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘scales’ 0.2.5 is already loaded, but >= 0.3.0 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.3 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: Your version of R is outdated. You must upgrade R first. Then you must run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I just install again ggplot2 and everything worked again. It installed also scales 0.4.2, so it solved the problem by itself.

Comment: Where did you find scales 0.4.2? The latest version on CRAN is 0.4.1.